# Blog Archive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have an archive page on my blog that looks like [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20200401215502/https://jamesclear.com/articles) (check under the heading **All Articles by Date**) with a single year on the top, then the month & date with the article name under it.

I have this posts array with type `Meta` that looks like:

```
export type Meta = {
    title: string
    date: Date
    lastEdited?: Date
    description: string
    slug: string
    tags: Array<Tag>
    image?: string
    author: string
    isPublished?: Boolean
}
```

And I made it work but results in `year` being on side-by-side using:

```
import React from 'react'

import { getYearMonthDate } from '@/utils/index'

import type { Meta } from '@/types/index'

export const Archive = ({ tutorials }: { tutorials: Meta }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {tutorials.map((tutorial: Meta) => {
                const [year, month, date] = getYearMonthDate(tutorial.date)
                let archiveYear
                return (
                    <li key={tutorial.slug}>
                        <h3 className="archiveYear">{year}</h3>
                        <span className="archiveDay">
                            {month} {date}
                        </span>
                        <a className="archiveLink">{tutorial.title}</a>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

I know I need to use a for-loop & track the old year & compare it with the new one & use an array to push data but that would result in ugly HTML markup.

Is there any way to make it look like the desired result. If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I didn't quiet got the question but use hashmap instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using `Map`. First, I used a `for` loop & put my blog data in a `Map` in the format `year` as `key` & `post[]` as `value`.

## utils/index.ts

```
import { format, parseISO, getYear as gY, getDate as gD } from 'date-fns'

export const formatDate = (date: string) => format(parseISO(date), 'MMMM dd, yyyy')

export const getYear = (date: Date) => gY(new Date(date))
export const getMonth = (date: Date) => format(new Date(date), 'MMMM')
export const getDate = (date: Date) => gD(new Date(date))
```

## Archive,tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

import { getYear, getMonth, getDate } from '@/utils/index'

import type { Meta } from '@/types/index'

export const Archive = ({
    postType,
    posts,
}: {
    postType: 'essay' | 'tutorial' | 'snippet'
    posts: Meta[]
}) => {
    const archive = new Map()
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        const post: Meta = posts[i]
        const year = getYear(post.date)
        if (!archive.has(year)) {
            archive.set(year, [post])
        } else {
            const oldArchive = archive.get(year)
            archive.set(year, [...oldArchive, post])
        }
    }

    return (
        <ul className="grid grid-cols-[1fr,min(90ch,calc(100%-64px)),1fr] gap-8 archive mb-64">
            {Array.from(archive.entries()).map(([archiveYear, posts], i) => {
                return (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <h3 className="text-3xl font-bold archiveYear">{archiveYear}</h3>
                        {posts.map((post: Meta) => {
                            const month = getMonth(post.date)
                            const date = getDate(post.date)
                            return (
                                <div
                                    className="grid grid-cols-[144px,calc(100%-144px)] my-2 text-lg font-medium"
                                    key={post.slug}
                                >
                                    <span className="text-gray-700 archiveDay dark:text-gray-300">
                                        {month} {date}
                                    </span>
                                    <Link href={`/${postType}/${post.slug}`}>
                                        <a className="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 archiveLink">{post.title}</a>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```